# What is the monotonicity of a polygon?

Tags: geometry, algorithms, computer-science, computational-geometry, polygons

What is the monotonicity of a polygon and why is it necessary to check the monotonicity?

Answer (score 3):

A monotone polygon is such that it is crossed at most two times by lines perpendicular to a given direction.

That means that the polygon can be split in two chains of vertices that are sorted in that direction. Sorted order is beneficial as it can often reduce the complexity of computations.

For instance, the convex hull of a monotone polygon can be computed in time proportional to the number of vertices, O(N).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_polygon

Comment: why it is necessary to chek the monotonicity of polygon

Comment: @UmerJaved: provide more context.

Comment: basically i want to write a c program to chek the monotonicity of a random generated polygon most of the topic are based on triangularity of polygon

Comment: @UmerJaved: triangularity ?